# How to split string by regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to split text by regex between character "@" and list of characters ([,.!?{} ]). Example, i have the next text

> @test, @{@test2, dasdas. @test3?} @test4? @test5!

and i want to get the next array:

> 1. test
> 2. test2
> 3. test3
> 4. test4
> 5. test5

I try to use the next regular expression

> /@(.*?)[,{} !?.]/

but it return incorrect array.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/ or a similar tool, these are very helpful when debugging regex.

Comment: Please post the code. Is it JS?

Comment: No, it is Java with string split method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to match a `@` and then match and capture 1 or more alphanumeric symbols with `\w+`:

```
@(\w+)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQ2vN2/1)

Results:

```
test
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

In Java, you can simply *match* the substrings:

```
String s = "@test, @{@test2, dasdas. @test3?} @test4? @test5!";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/MVMTHJ) (or [another demo](http://ideone.com/MqTdxZ) with the results stored in an array).

Answer (score 0):

If it is JavaScript, the following works.

string1 = "@test, @{@test2, dasdas. @test3?} @test4? @test5!";

array1 = string1.split("@"); /* Array [ "", "test, ", "{", "test2, dasdas. ", "test3?} ", "test4? ", "test5!" ] */

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in Javascript:

```
var re = /@([^,.!?{}@]+)/g; 
var str = '@test, @{@test2, dasdas. @test3?} @test4? @test5!';
var m;
var arr;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;

    arr.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(arr);
//=> ["test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD1jW9/2)